# How do I understand how std::make_shared works?

Tags: c++, shared

I came across an elegant line of reading a binary file into a vector like this (that works):

```
std::ifstream ifs("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});
```

Instead since I want my vector to be a shared pointer I write:

```
std::ifstream ifs("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary);
auto sp = std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});
```

I.e just pass the vector constructor arguments to make_shared (as I usually do to create any shared pointer of any objects).
But I get: error: no matching function for call to 'make_shared'?

Detailed output:

/usr/include/c++/11.1.0/bits/shared_ptr.h|873 col 5| note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Tp = std::vector<char, std::allocator>]: deduced incomplete pack <std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits >, (no value)> for template parameter '_Args'
||     make_shared(_Args&&... __args)

Comment: did you forget to `#include <memory>`?

Comment: My first thought, but no I didn't

Comment: Because that is a variadic function that just forwards arguments to the constructor, the meaning of the `{}` you pass can't be deduced in this context, as there is no specific argument type declared at that position. You therefore need to pass an object of a specific type, in this case the relevant `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}` I guess - not a braced init list. The error might say that, had you quoted it...

Comment: Yes I figured is has something to do with the '{}' but I would like a simple explanation. I always thought the () of make_shared was the exactly same as () of the objects constructor..

Comment: @Jörgen `{}` in a function call means 'default-initialise this argument as per its type'. If the function is templated for that argument, how can the compiler know what type that is? And `std::make_shared<>()` must be templated because it just forwards arguments to the constructor for the contained type, but to do that it must know _exactly what type they are_. A braced init-list has no type (at least not an empty one, in this context; elsewhere e.g. `{42}` would deduce to `std::initializer_list<int>`).

Comment: @Jörgen - `{}` only has meaning when the target type is known. On it's own it's not part of the type system (heck, it isn't even an expression). When the target type for `{}` isn't known (such as when trying to deduce its type to begin with), it's meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
std::ifstream ifs("myfile.bin", std::ios::binary);
auto sp = std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{});
```

This is because you are using this variadic template:

```
template<class T, class... Args>
shared_ptr<T> make_shared( Args&&... args );
```

where every single argument type must be deducable, if not manually instantited. '{}' doesn't allow for argument deduction, hence the compiler error. That being sad, you can also explicitly instantiate the template:

```
auto sp = std::make_shared<std::vector<char>, std::istreambuf_iterator<char>,
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>>({ifs}, {});
```

In both cases, a type alias for the iterator might improve readability (`using InputIt = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;` or something along those lines).